# How to get the user's Active Directory groups from web service hosted in a Windows service

Tags: web-services, active-directory, windows-services

I have a web application that stores documents on the server. In some cases I need to place certain permissions per the user groups as they are stored in Active Directory.

I've setup a web service hosted in a Windows service on the server, and the server is making contact with this web service to get the data.

When I call the methods from a regular console application, everything works great, and also if I call the web service when hosted locally on my computer in a Windows service, everything works great as well.

The problem only occurs when on the server - my guess is that when no one is logged on to the server.

**Edit:** The user is found (I think) and I get "No groups found" as a result.

===========

**Another Edit:** I updated the code with further work I'm trying.

After many experiments method2 does not fit at all.
Method2 requires me to do logon to the system with the user I want to check in order to get his groups. This is something that cannot be done as I don't have that user password.

I believe the two other methods (1 & 3) are not working due to something with the network structure and will have to talk to my boss about it. I will update again if I have some progress.

===========

Here is a link to a C# code I use to get the groups, 3 different methods - none of them work.

```cs
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class ActiveDirectoryService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetGroups1(string endUsername)
        {
            string result;
            try
            {
                var list = new List<string>();
                var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
                var serviceUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
                var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
                var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, serviceUsername, password);
                var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, endUsername);

                if (userPrincipal == null)
                {
                    return "Failed to find user: " + endUsername;
                }

                var authorizationGroups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                WriteToLogDebug("GetGroups1.authorizationGroups.Count: " + authorizationGroups.Count());
                foreach (var current in authorizationGroups)
                {
                    if (current is GroupPrincipal)
                    {
                        var groupPrincipal = current as GroupPrincipal;
                        var groupPrincipalName = groupPrincipal?.Name;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(groupPrincipalName))
                        {
                            list.Add(groupPrincipalName);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!list.Any())
                {
                    result = "No groups found for user " + endUsername;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = string.Join(" & ", list);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = "Failed to get groups for user " + endUsername + ": " + ex.Message;
                WriteToLogException("GetGroups1." + ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetGroups2(string endUsername)
        {
            string result;
            var serviceUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];

            try
            {
                var list = new List<string>();

                IntPtr token = GetLogonUserToken();
                if (token == default(IntPtr))
                {
                    return "Failed to logon user: " + serviceUsername;
                }

                var windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
                WriteToLogDebug("GetGroups2.windowsIdentity.Groups.Count: " + windowsIdentity.Groups.Count());

                foreach (var current in windowsIdentity.Groups)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        list.Add(current.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        WriteToLogException("GetGroups2." + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                if (!list.Any())
                {
                    result = "No groups found for user " + serviceUsername;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = string.Join(" & ", list);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = "Failed to get groups for user " + serviceUsername + ": " + ex.Message;
                WriteToLogException("GetGroups2." + ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetGroups3(string endUsername)
        {
            var result = "No groups found";
            try
            {
                var directoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry();
                if (directoryEntry == null)
                {
                    result = "DirectoryEntry returned null";
                }
                else
                {
                    var list = new List<string>();
                    var directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
                    {
                        Filter = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + endUsername + "))"
                    };
                    if (directorySearcher == null)
                    {
                        WriteToLogDebug("GetGroups3.(directorySearcher == null): " + (directorySearcher == null));
                        return "Failed to initiate directorySearcher";
                    }

                    SearchResultCollection searchResultCollection = null;
                    try
                    {
                        searchResultCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll();
                        if (searchResultCollection == null)
                        {
                            WriteToLogDebug("GetGroups3.(searchResultCollection == null): " + (searchResultCollection == null));
                            return "Failed to find user: " + endUsername;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        WriteToLogException("GetGroups3.Failed: " + ex.Message);
                        return "Failed to find user " + endUsername + ": " + ex.Message;
                    }

                    if (searchResultCollection.Count == 0)
                    {
                        result = "No groups found for user " + endUsername;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WriteToLogDebug("GetGroups3.searchResultCollection.Count: " + searchResultCollection.Count);
                        foreach (var current in searchResultCollection)
                        {
                            var searchResult = current as SearchResult;
                            foreach (var group in searchResult?.Properties["memberOf"])
                            {
                                if (group != null)
                                    list.Add(group.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        result = string.Join(" & ", list);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = "Failed to get groups for user " + endUsername + ": " + ex.Message;
                WriteToLogException("GetGroups3.Failed: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }

        private IntPtr GetLogonUserToken()
        {
            try
            {
                var LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
                //var LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;
                //var LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4;
                //var LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5;
                //var LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7;
                //var LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8;
                //var LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

                var LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

                var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
                WriteToLogDebug("GetLogonUserToken.domain: " + domain);
                var serviceUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
                WriteToLogDebug("GetLogonUserToken.serviceUsername: " + serviceUsername);
                var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
                WriteToLogDebug("GetLogonUserToken.password: " + password);
                LogonUser(serviceUsername, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out IntPtr token);
                return token;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToLogException("GetLogonUserToken.Failed" + ex.Message);
            }
            return default(IntPtr);
        }

        private DirectoryEntry GetDirectoryEntry()
        {
            DirectoryEntry result;
            try
            {
                var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
                WriteToLogDebug("GetDirectoryEntry.domain: " + domain);
                var serviceUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
                WriteToLogDebug("GetDirectoryEntry.serviceUsername: " + serviceUsername);
                var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
                WriteToLogDebug("GetDirectoryEntry.password: " + password);
                result = new DirectoryEntry
                {
                    Username = serviceUsername,
                    Password = password,
                    Path = "LDAP://" + domain
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = null;
                WriteToLogException("GetDirectoryEntry.Failed: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Any suggestions how to get a user groups from a web service hosted by a windows service?

Thanks

Comment: So then what *is* happening on your server? Exception? Is the user even found?

Comment: The user is found (I believe) and I get "No groups found" as a result.

Comment: Which method gives you that result?.  I wouldn't expect GetGroups1 to work, since you're searching for your service user name, not your end user name.  loginUserName is no more meaningful than userName as either name applies to either user account.  I suggest serviceUserName and endUserName are more specific to avoid issues like that

Comment: I get "No groups found" by method 1 & 3. The second method gives me this message: "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.".
Sorry about the coding mistake, thanks. It is still the same result as both variables (userName and loginUserName) have access to active directory.

Comment: In `GetGroups1`, you are still searching for the username stored in your .config file, not the `userName` passed as a parameter.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Fixed the code above

Comment: You said, "user is found (I believe)", That "I believe" is concerning. You need to be sure if it's found or not before continuing, because you still don't know if the problem is "the account is not found" or "it's not finding the groups".

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I can only guess the user is found because I get a "No groups found" and not some other exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it was indeed a network block, after changing the domain used I managed to get the end users and their groups.
Thank you all for the help.